# How to specify Age/Gender on AdMob interstitials by code?

Tags: android, admob

The AdRequest object has a way to specify age and gender, but I can't find a way to specify this on the InterstitialAd object. Anyone knows how ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like InterstitialAd has a method `loadAd(AdRequest adRequest)` where I can set age and gender on the AdRequest object.

Answer (score 0):

use this method

```
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().setGender(1).setBirthday(birthday).build();
interstitial.loadAd(adRequest);
interstitial.show();
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know if there actually is any affect in specifying the age/gender? Do you have any experience with eCPM change?

Comment: @VidarVestnes I don't believe it has any impact. I suspect Admob in particular will be pulling that information directly from Google+